# Convert time in HH:MM format to date time (date set to today)

Tags: python, date, datetime, timezone

I get time in `HH:MM` format (e.g. **09:15**) from an API. 
How to convert it to a valid python datetime object, with the date set to current date?

I mean **09:15** should converted to **Mon, Aug 28 09:15:00 (current timezone) 2017**.

I tried this, but I'm looking for a clean solution:

```
datetime.strptime(datetime.today().strftime('%Y/%m/%d ') + '09:15', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
```

Comment: What do you mean by clean solution?

Comment: @JaiSharma: Something without converting today date to string, then appending to the string. For example, set today as date of `datetime.strptime('09:15', '%H:%M')` returned object.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can first convert `time` string to `datetime` object and then replace attributes `year`, `month` and `day`:

```
now = datetime.today()

print (datetime.strptime('09:15', '%H:%M'))
1900-01-01 09:15:00

a = datetime.strptime('09:15', '%H:%M').replace(year=now.year,month=now.month,day=now.day)
print (a)
2017-08-28 09:15:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace`:

```
from datetime import  datetime

datetime.today().replace(hour=9, minute=15, second=0, microsecond=0)
```

Comment: I have a string, `09:15`, you mean I first split it by colon?

Comment: Please describe what you want to convert to what. I expected that you want to get current time with hours and minutes changed.

Comment: you're right, but I have a string which I get from somewhere else.